# Outsystems:Is it possible to have same user in different tenants in a Multi-tenant application

Tags: multi-tenant, outsystems

I created a multi-tenant application where each tenant have different set of users. I am trying to implement a functionality where same user might exist in different tenants. Does outsystems provide such functionality or I have to create my custom logic ?
Right now, I did create a user having same username in 2 different tenants and during login I am showing user to select tenants. But on changing tenants and logging to that tenant, the environment doesn't switch to that tenant that user has selected.

Below is the image of the logic of switching tenants and logging in the customer.

[image]

During debugging I saw that after executing *TenantSwitch* action it did change the *Site.TenantID* property but after *User_Login* action is reverted to the first tenant not the one user selected.

Answer (score 2):

When you use User_Login(), the system will log you in the first Tenant it finds in the DB that has that username, thus ignoring your TenantSwitch().

So, if you want to login to a *specific* Tenant in your case, you need to be more explicit and instead use the Login() action - after the tenant switch.

For a thorough explanation of this, with example code, please check out the following deepdive [Master Class on Multi-Tenancy](https://www.outsystems.com/learn/lesson/1138/master-class-on-multi-tenancy/) starting around the 27:20 minute mark.

Comment: I followed your approach, after User_login I retrieved the User id and performed tenant switching followed by Login action.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't available out of the box as OutSystems assigns users (and all entities) to a specific tenant. Entities belonging to single tenanted modules are assigned to the default tenant.

OutSystems uses a hidden .Tenant_Id attribute on each entity to indicate which tenant that user belongs to. You can unhide this attribute for the users entity by selecting it, clicking More... and then ticking the relevant box in the Advanced tab. You can then access the attribute directly, but be aware this will hinder OutSystems' ability to do some of the stuff it does automatically to ensure that you access tenant specific data.

When you use the User_Login action OutSystems will deduce which tenant to use from the User.Tenant_Id attribute regardless of which tenant you've switched it to previously. The user would need an account for each tenant they need to use, but there's no reason this couldn't be done behind the scenes with OS fetching the correct username before logging in. You'd need to ensure they all stay in sync though, especially the passwords ofc.